# How can I send to view a DTO and Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Dto

```
public class homePageDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<Yazi> yazi { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Yorum> yorum { get; set; }
}
```

My ActionMethod

```
public ActionResult Post(int pid)
{
    homePageDTO obj = new homePageDTO();
    obj.yazi = ent.Yazi.Where(x=>(x.YaziID==(int)pid)).ToList();
    obj.yorum = ent.Yorum.Where(x => (x.YorumNo == (int)pid)).ToList();

    return View(obj);
}
```

My multi model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication15.Models
{
    public class BigViewModel
    {
        public homePageDTO home { get; set; }
        public Yorum Yorrum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My View

```
  @model WebApplication15.Models.BigViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Post";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@foreach (var item in Model.home.yazi)
{
    <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('/content/img/post-bg.jpg')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading"> 

                        <h1>@item.YaziUstBaslik</h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                        <span class="subheading"><b>@item.YaziAltBaslik</b></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Post Content -->
    <article>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <p>@item.Yazi1</p>
                    <p class="alert alert-warning">Yollayan @item.YazarKullaniciAdi-@item.YaziTarih</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>

    <hr>
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Yorum
        </th>
        <th>
            Yorum Sahibi
        </th>
        <th>
            Tarihi
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var x in Model.home.yorum)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @x.Yorum1
            </td>
            <td>
                @x.YorumSahibi
            </td>
            <td>
                @x.YorumTarihi
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Yeni Yorum</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Selam</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>nasdsadasdasda</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Yolla</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

ERROR

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebApplication15.Models.homePageDTO', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication15.Models.BigViewModel'.

It was dissolved

My new action method

```
public ActionResult Post(int pid)
        {
            BigViewModel bigyorum = new BigViewModel();
            bigyorum.home = new homePageDTO();
            bigyorum.home.yazi = ent.Yazi.Where(x=>(x.YaziID==(int)pid)).ToList();
            bigyorum.home.yorum = ent.Yorum.Where(x => (x.YorumNo == (int)pid)).ToList();
            return View(bigyorum);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the model that is related in the view, in the first line of the view set this:

```
@model  WebApplication15.Models.homePageDTO
```

I think homePageDTO is in the namespace WebApplication15.Models, if not, put the correct namespace.

With your update:

In your action, you are passing an object of type homePageDTO:

```
public ActionResult Post(int pid)
{
    homePageDTO obj = new homePageDTO();
    obj.yazi = ent.Yazi.Where(x=>(x.YaziID==(int)pid)).ToList();
    obj.yorum = ent.Yorum.Where(x => (x.YorumNo == (int)pid)).ToList();

    return View(obj);
}
```

and in your view, yo have:

```
@model WebApplication15.Models.BigViewModel
```

There are differents objects, the type of the object that you pass from the action to the view, must be the same that you declare in the view.

So, change the action to return a **BigViewModel** or change in your view to **homePageDTO**

Comment: Thank you for your response , İ forget using line .İ Update this. Please look again .

Comment: @MertYavuz a view only can have one model, so, you need to declare only model homePageDTO, because this class has two properties (yazi and yorum), next you can access to this using: Model.yazi and Model.yorum

Comment: Thank you but i have new error , i update this , please look again .

Comment: Thank you for your all response. İ fixed .